# File Path of Access Database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm working with vb.net 2008 as well. But I have a question.How to remove a file path like this C:\users\myDocu\debug\Dbase.accdb and I only want is the file name Dbase.accdb. Because I want to transfer my files in another computer but the problem is the file path. I always need to change the entire location in my codes to run without debug.

Answer (score 1):

To get the filename without the path, you can use [`Path.GetFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

But if you want a painless way to find a place to store your database, consider putting it into the application data folder (`AppData`). You can get this folder with [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx), using it like this:

```
Dim pathToDb = Path.Combine(
                    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), 
                    "Dbase.accdb")
```

if you want to use the file locally. If you want to share the file between different instances of your application in a network, put the path e.g. in a config file like `App.Config`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Dim FullFilePath As String  
Dim FileName As String  

FullFilePath = "C:\users\myDocu\debug\Dbase.accdb"  
FileName = Mid(FullFilePath,InStrRev(FullFilePath,"\") + 1)
```